# why pd.read_sql_query is not fetching the time zone info from the DB

Tags: python, pandas, timezone-offset, milliseconds

I am trying to fetch data from various columns of different datetime datatypes (with and without timezone details) from Oracle DB into pandas DataFrame.

[image: various types of datetime columns]

As you can see column `c2` have timezone in it. When I try to fetch the same in pandas Dataframe using the below python code, somehow the timezone details are not being fetched.

```
data = pd.read_sql_query(select_query, connection_string, chunksize=chunk_size)
```

I am not sure, if I need to add any addtional flag in the `read_sql_query` method. Please point me to what I am missing here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to the desired format in your own function and apply this function to the datetime column(s):

```
def format_dt(dt):
    return dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3] \
            + " " + dt.strftime("%z")[0:3] \
            + ":" + dt.strftime("%z")[-2:]

df['dt_form'] = df['datetime'].apply(format_dt)
```